# Understanding arguments of QMetaObject :: invokeMethod - QtQuick

Tags: qt, qt-quick

From: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtbinding.html#calling-functions

`QMetaObject :: invokeMethod (object, "myQmlFunction", Q_RETURN_ARG(QVariant, returnedValue), Q_ARG(QVariant, msg));`

**but, the function arguments say:**

From: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod

`bool QMetaObject::invokeMethod ( QObject * obj, const char * member, Qt::ConnectionType`   `type, QGenericReturnArgument ret, QGenericArgument val0 = QGenericArgument( 0 ),`   `QGenericArgument val1 = QGenericArgument(), QGenericArgument val2 = QGenericArgument(),`   `QGenericArgument val3 = QGenericArgument(), QGenericArgument val4 = QGenericArgument(),`   `QGenericArgument val5 = QGenericArgument(), QGenericArgument val6 = QGenericArgument(),`  `QGenericArgument val7 = QGenericArgument(), QGenericArgument val8 = QGenericArgument(),`   `QGenericArgument val9 = QGenericArgument() ) [static]`

**So, the third argument to this function is:**
`Qt::ConnectionType`

***How does `Q_RETURN_ARG (QVariant, returnedValue)` correspond to `Qt::ConnectionType`?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[look again at the documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod-2) there are multiple overloads of `invokeMethod` including one for:

```
bool QMetaObject::invokeMethod ( QObject * obj, const char * member, 
               QGenericReturnArgument ret, 
               QGenericArgument val0 = QGenericArgument( 0 ), 
               QGenericArgument val1 = QGenericArgument(), 
               QGenericArgument val2 = QGenericArgument(), 
               QGenericArgument val3 = QGenericArgument(), 
               QGenericArgument val4 = QGenericArgument(), 
               QGenericArgument val5 = QGenericArgument(), 
               QGenericArgument val6 = QGenericArgument(), 
               QGenericArgument val7 = QGenericArgument(), 
               QGenericArgument val8 = QGenericArgument(), 
               QGenericArgument val9 = QGenericArgument() ) [static]
```

so the caller doesn't need to specify the connection type and/or care about the return argument

Comment: AH! They have used a different overloaded function. Thanks.